# Como identificar a ausencia de um termo num arquivo usando PERL

Tags: arquivo, perl

Ola, preciso de uma ajuda aqui.
Estou escrevendo um programa perl que ira identificar certos padroes num arquivo de texto usando regex. Porem, quando o termo buscado nao estiver presente no texto, preciso que o programa informe isso ao usuario.
Eu abro o arquivo e salvo num `array` e percorro ele com um laço `for`. Uso `if` para encontrar meu padrao e imprimi-lo. Quando adiciono `elsif`ou `else`, o programa imprime para cada linha que ele percorreu que nao encontrou o padrao. Precisava que ele imprimisse apenas ao chegar ao fim do documento se nao achar o padrao. alguem sabe como fazer isso? Talvez com `while`. Valeu o/

```
for($i=0; $i<=$#report; $i++){
    if($report[$i] =~ /target/){
       chomp $report[$i];
       print "$report[$i]";
    }
    else{
       print "not found\t";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar uma variável que regista se o padrão foi encontrado. Por exemplo:

```
my $found=0;
for($i=0; $i<=$#report; $i++){
   if($report[$i] =~ /target/){
      chomp $report[$i];
      print "$report[$i]";
      $found=1;
   }
}

print "not found\t" if (!$found);
```

Answer (score 0):

Já agora uma versão um pouco mais criptica:

```
print ( join(";", grep /target/,@report) || "not found\t")
```

Onde:

- `grep /target/,@report` dá a lista dos elementos do report que fazem match;

(Exemplo: `grep /33/, (1..300)` ---> `33 133 233`)